# Testing a queueable class containing a future callout

Tags: apex, unit-test, callout, future, queueable-apex

I have a queueable class that makes callouts (@future(callout=true)) in the execute method. When I manually test this, everything works correctly. But when I set up my test class, it gives me the "You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out" error. I don't have any DML statements apart from in my testSetup class. And I have Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() surrounding the enqueueJob.

I can test the callouts (and they test successfully) if I call this method directly, but I can't test the execute method (which calls the callout method).

i.e. this works:

```
QueueClass.makeCallouts(list);
```

But this doesn't (gives the commit error):

```
System.enqueueJob(new QueueClass(list));
```

For reference, here is the portion of my execute class that runs prior to the error:

```
settings = tokens.getInstance(id);
Boolean updated;
if (settings.Access_Expiration__c < Datetime.now()){
    //stuff that doesn't run
} else {
    updated = True;
}
if (updated){
    makeCallouts(list);
}
```

Can we not test callouts from queueable apex, can I not test the execute method, or am I missing something?

Comment: This question seems to be exactly the same as a situation I already answered elsewhere (making it easy for me to find). If you disagree that you are facing the same issue, the post can be reopened.

Comment: Thanks Adrian - this is a brilliant solution. I stumbled across another one that didn't quite get to this point that I will try to find again and link back to this answer.